In C# is there some clever way to instantiate a property if it's currently null, with a really simple syntax?
I wish there were a way in C# to specify that when I'm accessing a nullable type property, that if the current value is null, please emplace a new value by calling the Primary Constructor, with parameters I specify, and then give me that.
public SomeType some_property { get; set; }

Because today, my code gets super ugly everywhere:
if (o.some_property == null) o.some_property = new SomeType();
o.some_property.some_field = 7;

When I wish I could do this:
o.some_property!().some_field = 7;
o.some_property!("Sam", 7).some_field = 7;

Or some simpler syntax...  I'm open to suggestions.
Ideally the parameters to the constructor wouldn't even be evaluated if the property is not currently null...  Does it need to be a lambda?  That gets ugly real quick again...
I could envision different constructor patterns:
o.some_property!{X=1,Y=2}.some_field = 7;

And if I'm calling a parameterless constructor, give me something really simple?
o.some_property!!.some_field = 7;

Please?  Does something like this exist?

some_property ??= new SomeType(); should do it, note ??=.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization

@Charlieface your first alleged duplicate isn't at all on point (in fact it's the opposite question) and the second doesn't address properties which OP specifically asks about. This should be reopened.

@EmperorEto Added a couple more dupes, both of which mention the options in your answer.

Why not just initialize your property on initialization if your code allows but can't handle nulls?

@blindy constructing may be expensive so you might not want it done unless it's needed

@charlieface you win this round, Trebeck. :D

You're talking about trying to initialize the field on every single access, and you're worried about performance? What about multi-threaded access? I don't see any locks anywhere, so do you just live with data corruption? Do you also add locks on every access too? Just initialize the fields like a normal human being, or write better code if having uninitialized data is a valid state, this is not a solution to anything.

@Blindy what's with the attitude? No it's not initialized on every access. Look at my answer. It checks for null on the backing field and if null then constructs and assigns, once. The only thing that happens every time is the null check - just like with the coalescing operator. And the coalescing operator isn't threadsafe either.

Lazy construction is a long established pattern. Your hostility to it is perplexing.

_some_property ?? (_some_property = new SomeType()) is exactly "trying to initialize the field on every single access", what's perplexing is that you don't seem to understand that. That is fine, I'm just saying. And lazy construction might be a long established pattern, but it's generally to be avoided because of threading issues. The C# singleton pattern, for example, as code smelly as it is, looks nothing like this (unlike other languages like C++).

"then constructs and assigns, once" -- absolutely, categorically not. You are fundamentally not understanding multi-threaded race conditions if you believe that. If you take anything from this OP, take this: this pattern will absolutely crash and burn in any multi-threaded scenario.

@blindy your reply didn't show in my box so I just saw this. I never claimed this was categorically threadsafe. The null coalescing operator which others suggested is also not threadsafe. Tons of code isn't thread safe, including most .net containers, because it doesn't need to be. That doesn't automatically make it wrong. It makes it not thread safe.

Sure, but you know what is thread safe? Initializing the field with a property initializer. Tons of code isn't thread safe, or correct, or many things, you're right, but you can choose to write correct code instead.

You could define the default value of the property, this way the default value will not be null.
public SomeType some_property { get; set; } = new();

The downside of this approach is that every time you create an instance of the class that has this property, an instance of this property will also be created. So, if you don't need it in most cases, this approach is not the best.

You can use the null-coalescing operators
o.some_property ??= new SomeType().some_field = 7;


Sure, but I'm trying to break the Law Of Demeter here, so what does the entire line look like?  o.some_property.some_field = 7; is my goal, so...  (o.some_property ??= new SomeType()).some_field = 7;  Is that it?  No, right, because I actually want to emplace that SomeType in the some_property property...

@MattCruikshank Please check the MS document referenced in answer. It will hopefully answer all your doubts. Anyway, find the edit in answer

I think your answer is just a bit off, I think it needs to be:
(o.some_property ??= new SomeType()).some_field = 7;

Oooh, and in my case it actually works to skip the SomeType(), so I can just do:
(o.some_property ??= new()).some_field = 7;

I hope I'm not misunderstanding, but (a) I agree there should be, but there isn't a great simple way to do this, but (b) the best way I know how to do this is as follows:
private SomeType? _some_property;
public SomeType some_property 
{ 
   get => _some_property ?? (_some_property = new SomeType());
   set => _some_property = value;
}

This does, then, allow you to write:
o.some_property.some_field = 7;

One thing you could do in Visual Studio is make a code snippet to write out the property definition, including the backing field and setter/getter, fairly easily. This is a common pattern for ICommand properties in MVVM view models so I use a snippet that does just that.
Alternatively, there's always Lazy<T>. See here. However you have to either provide a constructor lambda or it uses reflection, so that isn't ideal.
